# Illustrator: Quotation marks not working for Google Font Karla

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typefaces, ttf

I'm using the Google Font Karla in Adobe Illustrator CC and whenever I try to type quotation marks it changes them to the default typeface (Myriad Pro). I tried toggling on and off "use smart quotes" but it changes nothing.

[image: Karla Bold with (ugly) Myriad Pro quotation marks]

When I use Karla in Google docs it displays the quotes fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font doesn't include quotation marks. Google Docs is simply using a different font to replace the marks (looks like Helvetica or something with similar marks).

Compare the marks shown in Google Docs to what should be similarly designed glyphs and you'll see they're nothing alike...

[image]

Here is a screenshot of all the glyphs included in Karla:

[image]

Interestingly the font does include single quotation marks so there's no good reason they shouldn't have the double quotation marks.

Comment: I'm quickly learning the limitations of Google Fonts...I guess I'll make my own double quotes. Thank you.

Comment: @kamalcon Try [Karmilla](https://github.com/ms-studio/karmilla).